# Laravel Not Adding Custom Headers

Tags: php, http, laravel, http-headers

Using laravel, I am attempting to add my own headers to all responses from the server.

I have the following in `filters.php`:

```
App::after(function($request, $response)
{
    // security related 
    $response->headers->set('X-Frame-Options','deny'); // Anti clickjacking
    $response->headers->set('X-XSS-Protection', '1; mode=block'); // Anti cross site scripting (XSS)
    $response->headers->set('X-Content-Type-Options', 'nosniff'); // Reduce exposure to drive-by dl attacks
    $response->headers->set('Content-Security-Policy', 'default-src \'self\''); // Reduce risk of XSS, clickjacking, and other stuff
    // Don't cache stuff (we'll be updating the page frequently)
    $response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'nocache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
    $response->headers->set('Pragma', 'no-cache');
    $response->headers->set('Expires', 'Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT');
    // CRITICAL: do NOT delete
    $response->headers->set('X-Archer', 'DANGER ZONE');
});
```

Yet no new headers show up when I test it:

```
[tesla | ~] => curl -o/dev/null -s -D - localhost
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 10 Dec 2014 23:13:30 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.2
Content-Length: 974
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

[tesla | ~] =>
```

I have no error or warnings in my log files. How could this be?

Comment: Which version of Laravel? In 4, it's `header()` instead of `headers->set()` http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses

Comment: @mopo922 I am using 4.2, however changing it to `$response->header('key','val')` didn't change anything

Comment: The other thing you could try is just normal PHP `header()`

Comment: Placing that in `App::after` produces an error saying headers were already sent, but placing it in `App:before` does work. I was just hoping there was a more laravel way to go about doing it :)

Comment: In that case, maybe App::after is too late to add headers, Laravel way or not.

Comment: I have to ask - what is the Archer "danger zone" heading for?

Comment: @TheShiftExchange It's an Archer reference. Great show, you should try it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archer_%28TV_series%29

Comment: lol - I know Archer - I watch it all the time. I meant why is it in your headers? An "easter egg"? :)

Comment: @TheShiftExchange yes :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this out: In the controller function that calls the view, follow with a call to the 'Response' class:

```
$contents = View::make('your_view')->with('data', $data);
$response = Response::make($contents, 200);
$response->header('X-Frame-Options','deny'); // Anti clickjacking
$response->header('X-XSS-Protection', '1; mode=block'); // Anti cross site scripting (XSS)
$response->header('X-Content-Type-Options', 'nosniff'); // Reduce exposure to drive-by dl attacks
$response->header('Content-Security-Policy', 'default-src \'self\''); // Reduce risk of XSS, clickjacking, and other stuff
    // Don't cache stuff (we'll be updating the page frequently)
$response->header('Cache-Control', 'nocache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
$response->header('Pragma', 'no-cache');
$response->header('Expires', 'Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT');
return $response;
```

Of course you could refactor the above and include it in a helper function.

Comment: `$response->header('X-Archer', 'DANGER ZONE');` why?

Comment: @LukasBernhard -- you can disregard that custom header. Removed.

Comment: This isn't working for me make() undefined though class is inherited for RESPONSE

Answer (score 0):

Also an option:

```
return Response::view('view_name', [
    'data' => $data,
  ])->header('X-Frame-Options','deny');
```

Found in: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#basic-responses

Look at **Creating Custom Responses**

Answer (score 0):

```
return response($content)
            ->header('Content-Type', $type)
            ->header('X-Header-One', 'Header Value')
            ->header('X-Header-Two', 'Header Value');
```

laravel 5.8